# Combining two lists to string

Tags: python, string, list

Actually I'm trying to merge two lists to one string but keep them ordered meaning:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

result = "1one2two3three4four5five"
```

(lists always have the same length but vary in contents)

At the moment I'm doing it this way:

```
result = ""
i = 0

for entry in list1:
    result += entry + list2[i]
    i += 1
```

I think there must be a more pythonic way to do this but I don't know it actually.

May someone of you can help me out on this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

print ''.join([str(a) + b for a,b in zip(list1,list2)])
```

```
1one2two3three4four5five
```

Comment: This is a [generator expression](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) used alongside [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

Comment: Make it a list comprehension and it'll be faster still. By giving `.join()` a generator expression, Python has to create a list from it *anyway* because `.join()` needs to scan the input twice, once to calculate the total length of the output and once to generate the output. A `[list comprehension]` is faster than `list(generator expression)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters True but simplicity is probably more important

Comment: @jamylak: The extra `[..]` brackets are almost always worth it. It doesn't add much.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's exactly what i was looking for. Just have to wait another 7 minutes before accepting the answer

Comment: Note that list comprehensions are only a better option where you know the whole thing is going to be exhausted.

Comment: I can see this new listcomp fandom is going to be a point of continuing controversy. :-/  For my part, worrying about O(1) differences in performance as a result of implementation details feels very unpythonic to me.  @Lattyware: I can also think of exhaustion cases where I'd prefer a genexp-- using `max` and `min`, for example.

Comment: @DSM Well, in that case, it might not be exhausted - I agree it's not as clear cut in cases like that. In general, I'd agree with you in saying that in general, you are better off just going with the generator expression. If you happen to know that the whole thing will definitely be exhausted, you can go ahead and make it a list comp, but it's probably not worth the effort.

Comment: @Lattyware: I'm sure it's just the fact I haven't had coffee yet that I'm missing something, but doesn't `max` always need to exhaust?  How would you know the last term isn't bigger than the ones you've seen so far otherwise?  Or do you only mean that in general (`next`, say) we don't need to exhaust?  (Which obviously I agree with.  I was just trying to think of an example where I would exhaust but never use a listcomp.)

Comment: @DSM Oh wow, for some reason i definitely read your post as `any` and `all` - apparently I haven't had my coffee either.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> ''.join(map(str, itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(list1, list2))))
1one2two3three4four5five'
```

**Explanation:**

- `zip(list1, list2)` creates a list containing tuples of matching elements from the two lists:

  ```
  >>> zip(list1, list2)
  [(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four'), (5, 'five')]
  ```
- [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) flattens that nested list:

  ```
  >>> list(chain.from_iterable(zip(list1, list2)))
  [1, 'one', 2, 'two', 3, 'three', 4, 'four', 5, 'five']
  ```
- Now we need to ensure that there are only strings, so we apply `str()` to all items using `map()`
- Eventually `''.join(...)` merges the list items into a single string with no separator.

Comment: I would argue this is the most flexible, pythonic answer. The advantage here is one could happily add more iterables to `zip()` and it would work perfectly, the other answers would all require alteration depending on the number of iterables.

Comment: @Lattyware flexible, yes but definitely overkill for this particular situation

Comment: @Lattyware: for me, Ashwini's answer is the most pythonic - "simple is better than complex", you know.

Comment: I don't really feel this is that much more complex - maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 4):

Using [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) with `str.join()` and `zip()`:

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> list2 = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

>>> "".join("{0}{1}".format(x,y) for x,y in zip(list1,list2))
'1one2two3three4four5five'
```

`zip(list1,list2)` returns something like this:
`[(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four'), (5, 'five')]`.

Now for each item of this list we apply the string formatting and then join the whole generator expression using `str.join()`.

Comment: or just `'{}{}'.format(*p) for p in...`

Comment: @thg435 This way it's clearer

Comment: @jamylak: I'm not a big `format` fan, so I'd personally use `"%d%s" % p for p...`.

Comment: @thg435 you should use `format()`, as it might replace % based formatting sooner or later. http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#pep-3101-a-new-approach-to-string-formatting

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I don't think they ever dare.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Yeah it's not going to for a long time. It might even stay forever haha

Comment: @jamylak I am in favor of `format` and I hope they remove that old formatting asap. ;)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I'm also in favor of format

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> ''.join(str(n)+s for (n,s) in zip(list1, list2))
'1one2two3three4four5five'
```

Here:

- `for (n,s) in zip(list1, list2)` iterates over pairs of elements in `list1` and `list2` (i.e. `1` and `"one"` etc);
- `str(n)+s` converts each pair into a string (e.g. `"1one"`);
- `''.join(...)` merges the results into a single string.