# Concatenate two lists of different length in between each other

Tags: python, concatenation

I have two list of different sizes, n and n-1. I have to concatenate two lists that look like this

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = ['-','-']
```

They have to be concatenated to get s.th like this

```
str_out = 'a-b-c'
```

I have tried to figure out an elegant way to do this but only managed to come up with this solution

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = ['-','-']
string2 = ''

for index,item in enumerate(list1):
    string2 = string2 + item + list2[index-1]

print(string2)
```

which prints

```
'a-b-c-'
```

I am looking for a nicer implementation or how I can get rid of the final dash (`-`)

EDIT: To clarify, the lists will be dynamic and list2 can contain arbitrary characters.

e.g: `list2 = ['*','-']`

Comment: Will one list always be one shorter than the other? And if so, do you know which?

Comment: yes, list2 will always be shorter by 1

Comment: `''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(list1,list2,fillvalue='')))` (`izip_longest` in Python2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining two lists to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703590/combining-two-lists-to-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
from itertools import chain
"".join(x for x in chain(*map(None, list1, list2)) if x is not None)
```

**Update** add izip_longest version:

```
from itertools import chain, izip_longest
"".join(x for x in chain(*izip_longest(list1, list2)) if x is not None)
```

**Update** py3 version:

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest
"".join(x for x in chain(*zip_longest(list1, list2)) if x is not None)
```

Comment: If you already use the itertools, why not the `izip_longest()`?

Comment: Yes, `izip_longest` can be used here too:
`"".join(x for x in chain(*izip_longest(list1, list2)) if x is not None)`

Comment: I have `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` for the first solution in Python 3, so it's a Python 2-only solution.

Comment: In python3 `"".join(x for x in chain(*zip_longest(list1, list2)) if x is not None)` will work.

Comment: @GennadyKandaurov I got this error when run in python 3:   TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, numpy.uint8 found

Comment: @Joe_Tz it's from `"".join()` since `"".join` requires an iterable of strings, if elements are not strings, convert them into strings with additional step: `"".join(map(str, x for x in chain(...)...))`

Answer (score 2):

You might use the `itertools`
Many posibilities, e.g.

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['-', '*']
''.join(map(''.join, itertools.izip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue='')))
''.join(itertools.chain(*itertools.izip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue='')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
In [32]: ''.join(i+j for i,j in zip(list1,list2+['']))
Out[32]: 'a-b-c'
```

Just add a black (`''`) element at end of `list2`. Then just apply `zip` and `join`.

Tried with another example,

```
In [36]: list2 = ['*','-']
In [37]: ''.join(i+j for i,j in zip(list1,list2+['']))
Out[37]: 'a*b-c'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your lists always correct, you can do:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = ['-','-']

res = []
for i1, i2 in zip(list1, list2):
    res.append(i1)
    res.append(i2)

res.append(list1[-1])

print ''.join(res)
```

Iterate on the two lists simultaneously, and add an item from `list1` and then from `list2`. When the loop terminates, you have one more item in `list1`, which you append manually.

Another solution would be having a separate counter for each list:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = ['-','-']

res = []
j = 0
for i1 in list1:
    res.append(i1)
    if j < len(list2):
        res.append(list2[j])
        j += 1

print ''.join(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **NumPy arrays**, as their indexing tools are very useful for the purpose of the OP:

```
list1 = np.array(['a','b','c'])
list2 = np.array(['*','-'])
final_list = np.zeros(len(l1) + len(l2)).astype('S1')
list3[0::2] = list1
list3[1::2] = list2

result_string = ''.join(list3)
```

The result will be:

```
'a*b-c'
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7946825/7007605) regarding interleaving lists:

```
''.join(val for pair in zip(list1, list2) for val in pair) + list1[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the first list to get a sublist with the same length as the second list, then apply [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to the result. `extend` is used to add the other elements of the first list:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = ['-','-']

my_list = [''.join(item) for item in zip(list1[:len(list2)], list2)]
my_list.extend(list1[len(list2):])
str_out = ''.join(my_list)
print(str_out)
# Output: 'a-b-c'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several external packages that have builtin functions for this kind of "interleaving" of iterables, just to show one of them: [`iteration_utilities.roundrobin`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/roundrobin.html) (note, that I'm the author of this library):

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import ManyIterables
>>> ManyIterables(['a','b','c'], ['-','-']).roundrobin().as_string()
'a-b-c'
>>> ManyIterables(['a','b','c'], ['-','*']).roundrobin().as_string()
'a-b*c'
```

The [`as_string`](http://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/Iterable.html#iteration_utilities.Iterable.as_string) is just a wrapped `''.join` call.

Just to name a few alternatives:

- [`toolz.interleave`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.interleave)
- [`more-itertools.interleave_longest`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.interleave_longest)

These are generalized solutions that work on an arbitary number of sequences and iterables. With only two iterables and if you don't want to use external packages using a `zip` or `itertools.zip_longest` approach (see other answers) is probably easier.

Answer (score -3):

```
from itertools import zip_longest,chain
list1 = ['a','b','c']    
list2 = ['*','-']
''.join(i+j for i,j in zip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue=''))
```

or:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']    
list2 = ['*','-']
def item_gen(list1, list2):
    for i,j in zip(list1, list2):
        yield i
        yield j
    yield list1[-1]

each = item_gen(list1, list2)
''.join(each)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer if have just updated my question, join won't work unfortunately